# :reason=>"Something is wrong with your configuration." GeoIP.dat Mutate Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have the following configuration for logstash.

There are 3 parts to this one is a generallog which we use for all applications they land in here.

second part is the application stats where in which we have a specific logger which will be configured to push the application statistics

third we have is the click stats when ever an event occurs on client side we may want to push it to the logstash on the upd address.

all 3 are udp based, we also use log4net to to send the logs to the logstash.

the base install did not have a GeoIP.dat file so got the file downloaded from the https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

have put the file in the /opt/logstash/GeoIPDataFile with a 777 permissions on the file and folder.

second thing is i have a country name and i need a way to show how many users form each country are viewing the application in last 24 hours.

so for that reason we also capture the country name as its in their profile in the application.

now i need a way to get the geo co-ordinates to use the tilemap in kibana.

What am i doing wrong.

if i take the geoIP { source -=> "country" section the logstash works fine.

when i check the

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -t -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
```

The configuration file is ok is what i receive. where am i going worng?

Any help would be great.

```
   input {
  udp {
    port => 5001
    type => generallog
  }
  udp {
    port => 5003
    type => applicationstats
  }
 udp {
    port => 5002
    type => clickstats
  }

}

filter {
  if [type] == "generallog" {

  grok {
      remove_field => message
      match => { message => "(?m)%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:sourcetimestamp} \[%{NUMBER:threadid}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} +- %{IPORHOST:requesthost} - %{WORD:applicationname} - %{WORD:envname} - %{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}" }
      }
    if !("_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
      mutate {
        replace => [ "message" , "%{logmessage}" ]
        replace => [ "host" , "%{requesthost}" ]
    add_tag => "generalLog"
      }
     }
  }

  if [type] == "applicationstats" {
    grok {
      remove_field => message
      match => { message => "(?m)%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:sourceTimestamp} \[%{NUMBER:threadid}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}  - %{WORD:envName}\|%{IPORHOST:actualHostMachine}\|%{WORD:applicationName}\|%{NUMBER:empId}\|%{WORD:regionCode}\|%{DATA:country}\|%{DATA:applicationName}\|%{NUMBER:staffapplicationId}\|%{WORD:applicationEvent}" }
      }

     geoip {
      source => "country"
      target => "geoip"
      database => "/opt/logstash/GeoIPDataFile/GeoIP.dat"
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
    }
    mutate {
      convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
    }

    if !("_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
      mutate {
    add_tag => "applicationstats"
        add_tag => [ "eventFor_%{applicationName}" ]

      }
     }
   }
  if [type] == "clickstats" {
    grok {
      remove_field => message
      match => { message => "(?m)%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:sourceTimestamp} \[%{NUMBER:threadid}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}  - %{IPORHOST:remoteIP}\|%{IPORHOST:fqdnHost}\|%{IPORHOST:actualHostMachine}\|%{WORD:applicationName}\|%{WORD:envName}\|(%{NUMBER:clickId})?\|(%{DATA:clickName})?\|%{DATA:clickEvent}\|%{WORD:domainName}\\%{WORD:userName}" }
      }
    if !("_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
      mutate {
        add_tag => "clicksStats"
        add_tag => [ "eventFor_%{clickName}" ]

          }
       }
   }
}

output {
if [type] == "applicationstats"  {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       index => "applicationstats-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}" 
       template => "/opt/logstash/templates/udp-applicationstats.json"  
       template_name => "applicationstats"
       template_overwrite => true
          }
  }
else if [type] == "clickstats"  {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       index => "clickstats-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}" 
       template => "/opt/logstash/templates/udp-clickstats.json"  
       template_name => "clickstats"
       template_overwrite => true
          }
  }

else if [type] == "generallog"  {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       index => "generallog-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}" 
       template => "/opt/logstash/templates/udp-generallog.json"  
       template_name => "generallog"
       template_overwrite => true
          }
  }
else{
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       index => "logstash-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"  
        }  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, the mutation which you're trying to do could be wrong. Could you please change your `mutate` as below:

```
    mutate {
        convert => { "geoip" => "float" }
        convert => { "coordinates" => "float" }
      }
```

I guess you've given the `mutate` as an array, and it's a `hash` type by origin. Try converting both the values individually. Your `database` path for `geoip` seems to be fine in your `filter`. Is that the whole error which you've mentioned in the question? If not update the question with the whole error if possible.

Refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert), for in depth explanations.

Comment: that is the only error in the logstash.log file in the /etc directory.

Comment: Did you try out with the changes I mentioned?

Comment: yes no luck Kulasangar. it seems to fail with the same error. all i want is per country i need a circle to show how many users.